# react-native: how to override the default style defined in a component

Tags: react-native

Let's say I want to use a Component with below defined style:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
  },
});
```

Can I override the base style with mine like this?

```
<Component style={backgroundColor: 'transparent'}></Component>
```

It didn't work for me, so wonder if this depends on if the Component supports the behavior.

Comment: It should work exactly that way, maybe the syntax is off? Try style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }} .

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The description is a bit vague. Is it a component you wrote your self? Assuming this it should work like this:

```js
export default React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(<View style={[ styles.container, this.props.style ]}>...</View>
  }
})

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
  },
});
```

Comment: it is a 3rd party component, I 'd rather not to modify it, thus the question.

Comment: Well, then you have to check their code, I guess. The only way to get any style changes into that component is via props. You have to look at their View elements and see if they apply any props to style properties. The wouldn't necessarily be named style either.

Comment: You can try wrapping the component with a view and add styles to it. (but it might not be applicable to all the children as there is no cascading)

Comment: While your answer doesn't address OP's concern, this was helpful to my team for a component that we control. Thanks, @dvinemultimedia.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to make everything fallback to the default styling when `this.props.style` is not defined?

Comment: It does this already, by applying the internal style class and this.props.style both as an array. Only the properties defined in this.props.style will override the local one. If this.props.stile is null or undefined or empty, the local style stays unchanged.

Comment: The `React.CreateClass` is deprecated. the developers can use `Component`, `PureComponent` or `StateLess` component to write a `react` component.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `style` props to your component and use an array inside your `View` element style props. But if the style props that come from props be an array, `react native` style props for elements cannot handle it. So use below function as a util:

```
exprot const styleJoiner = (...arg) => arg.flat(9).filter(a => a); // 9import is{ aStyleSheet custom} depthfrom number'react-native';
```

Now write your component like below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { styleJoiner } from 'utils';

export default (props)=> (
    <View style={styleJoiner(styles.container, props.style)}>
        ~~~
    </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
  }
});
```

It is safe to work.